# Spring MVC to connect 2 different web aplications

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a question about Spring MVC and my question about spring mvc is how to connect two web applications, for example in the first web application I write in a form my name and i have to send that information and display in the other web application.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Kevin. Can you add what you have already tried and how it doesn't accomplish what you want? Showing some work on your side increases the chance that someone wants to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although I personally do not have a problem with suggesting higher level design implementation, you generally need to provide some code that you need help with here. That  said, with MVC You are dealing with individual projects on  server that are separate domains. You may try including the two projects under a single domain to allow them to share data.

Comment: Can you explain why you want these to be separate applications instead of two pieces in the same application?

Comment: @chrylis because i have an exercise in my Spring course and i don't know where to start. I'm totally beginner in this framework

Comment: Then you'll need to provide more information about the requirement; it's not usual at all to do this (especially with modern CSRF concerns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it in spring MVC, I am going to explain a simple way to you.

1. first, get the values from your form and change it to JSON format.
2. then send it to another application in JSON format.
3. in other web application, get the JSON file and display it. Like this

here are some examples, you may try your own

**Getting JSON Value in a controller**

```
//You can use @RestController or @ResponseBody to send a response in JSON format 

@PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public MOResponse receiveNotification(@RequestBody MO mo) {
    studentService.getStudent(mo);
    MOResponse moResponse = new MOResponse("S1000", "Success");
    return moResponse;
}
```

**Sending POST request to another api**
*here ,this request is sending in String format but you can change to JSON format*

```
public void sendMT() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    final String uri = "http://localhost:7000/sms/send";
    try {
        String json = ow.writeValueAsString(mt);
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = RequestEntity.post(new URL(uri).toURI()).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(json);
        ResponseEntity<String> output = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in the above example, I have used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

*Remember this example for just getting an idea. you can create your own, best of luck*

Answer (score 0):

mi firts recomendation is to take the course 
https://dzone.com/articles/top-5-courses-to-learn-spring-boot-in-2019

Actually is easy to learn spring with spring boot, please review Spring boot, this is the solution a your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I take the course and Spring starts being easy for me